# How to change the iOS UITabBar badge value position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uitabbaritem

[image: three]

**Here's the code in my `AppDelegate.m`**:

```
RootTableViewController *fcTableViewController = [[RootTableViewController alloc]
                                                  initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
fcTableViewController.title = @"root";
UINavigationController *fcNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                  initWithRootViewController:fcTableViewController];
fcNavigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
fcNavigationController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"0";

// ?
fcNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1"]
                                           imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
fcNavigationController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);

FaiChouViewController *fcViewController = [[FaiChouViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *fcNController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fcViewController];
fcNController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
fcNController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"1";
// ...
UITabBarController *fcTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
fcTabBarController.viewControllers = @[fcNavigationController, fcNController, fcpNavigationController];

self.window.rootViewController = fcTabBarController;
```

[image: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;]

**Here's my question:**

Why's the badge value `1` on my phone not in the correct position?

And how to solve it?

Comment: Please post code, not a screen shot

Comment: Badge value 1 is showing fine on iPhone 5 and 6 but not on iPod. what your question is actually? your question is "Why's the badge value 1 on my phone not in the correct position?" whats does it mean? where you want your badge value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The day before the yesterday i faced the same problem, you can have a look in [here](https://github.com/ratulSharker/UITabbarItem-CustomBadge)

## Demo

[image]

Only two line of code can get you started

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  //supplying the animation parameter
  [UITabBarItem setDefaultAnimationProvider:[[DefaultTabbarBadgeAnimation alloc] init]];
  [UITabBarItem setDefaultConfigurationProvider:[[DefaultSystemLikeBadgeConfiguration alloc] init]];

  //rest of your code goes following...

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: does it serve your purpose ? @FaiChou